# Module categories for Fibonacci anyons

Tags: fusion-categories, modular-tensor-categories

What are the module categories over the modular tensor category **Fib** of Fibonacci anyons?

By [Ostrik's work](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0111139), we know these module categories correspond to separable algebras in **Fib**. I do not believe such things have been classified.

[Davydov and Booker](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.3537) show there are no nontrivial *commutative* separable algebras in **Fib**, but I do not see that they make a clear statement for this more general case, without commutativity.

My guess is that there are indeed no nontrivial module categories for **Fib**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is only one equivalence class of indecomposable module categories, namely the trivial one.

Let us look into the possible algebras. They are $1$ and $1\oplus \tau$, and both have a unique algebra structure. For the first this is trivial and for the second is basically saying that the $A_4$ subfactor is unique.
But $1\oplus\tau =\tau\otimes \bar\tau$ so it coincides with the internal action hom $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(\tau,\tau)$ of Fib as a module category over itself.

Here is another proof. The only possible connected étale (commutative) algebra is $1$, as the OP points out. Then by Corollary 3.8 in

> Davydov, A.; Nikshych, D.; Ostrik, V.: On the structure of the Witt group of braided fusion categories. Selecta Math. (N.S.) 19 (2013), no. 1, 237–269.

module categories are in one-to-one correspondence with braided autoequivalences of $\mathrm{Fib}\to\mathrm{Fib}$ for which there exist only the trivial one.

Comment: If you want to see more detail for this style of argument (eg, why are those the only possible algebras) we do a more elaborate example [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.2631).